# oci.exceptions.ServiceError while using python-sdk

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

while fetching metrics getting this error.
oci.exceptions.ServiceError: {'opc-request-id': 'irogegjeojgeakse', 'code': 'LimitExceeded', 'message': 'Query cannot result in more than 2000 streams.', 'status': 400}

Answer (score 0):

What is your question? The error message seems clear as to what the issue is. You will need to make queries to this API which are more fine-grained in the results they are requesting than the query you made which resulted in that error.